# setFrame in UIView animation doesn't move, only snaps in place

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiviewanimation

In my viewDidLoad method I place a button off to the left of the view, off screen.

Then I use these two methods to animate it:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self showButton];
}
```

And the method:

```
-(void) showButton {
    [myButton setTitle:[self getButtonTitle] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // animate in
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"button_in" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDone)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [myButton setFrame:kMyButtonFrameCenter]; // defined CGRect
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The button immediately appears and does not animate.  Further, the animationDone selector is called immediately.

Why doesn't it animate my button into the screen?

EDIT:  This has to have something to do with trying to start an animation while in viewDidAppear...

Comment: strangely if I wait a bit, the animation will work.

Answer (score 6):

I tried your animation code and it works fine.

Where do set the initial frame of the button? Is it possible that you mistakenly set the button's frame to `kMyButtonFrameCenter` before you start the animation? That would explain why the animationDone selector is called immediately.

Here is the code that works:

```
-(void) showButton {
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [myButton setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(-100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 30.0);
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];

    // animate in
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"button_in" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDone)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 30.0)]; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

As you see I did not change anything in your animation code. So I think the problem is the button's frame.

A bit off-topic: If you don't have build your app for iOS < 4 you might want to have a look at UIView's "animation with blocks" that came with iOS 4.0.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^void{myButton.frame = kMyButtonFrameCenter} completion:^(BOOL completed){NSLog(@"completed");}];
```

=== EDIT ===

After reading your comment, it seems that my suspicion is not correct. [inspire48](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472768/inspire48) points in the right direction with his answer. You should put the placement of the button inside the `viewDidAppear` method or in the `showButton` method to make sure that the button is placed outside the screen **before** you call the animation

Comment: I tried placing it in viewDidAppear but it had no effect.  However, I did find that by using a timer with a delay of 0.2 would make everything work.

Comment: Have you tried doing it like I did it in the code above? Because there it works. Do you have a lot of UIElements that need to be drawn when the view appears?

Comment: Yes, I just gave it a whirl.  I tried setting the frame right there, setting the 'center' and a few other things.  I finally simply set a timer to go off 0.2 seconds after viewDidAppear and everything works that way.  I still don't know why though.

Answer (score 3):

Put the animation call in viewDidAppear. viewDidLoad is used for more data-type setup. Any visual effects such as animations should go in viewDidAppear. You've confirmed this—it works if you wait a bit.

Comment: The animation call is in viewDidAppear but maybe it's helps to put the placement of the button in there as well (before you call the showButton method)

Comment: I tried putting the button placement in view did appear first, but it didn't help.